# CakePHP: value not being saved to Db

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to use Andras Kende's [CakePHP Shopping Cart](https://github.com/andraskende/cakephp-shopping-cart) in my own application, and I cant figure why the following changes will not work.

At the end of the order process, after paypal and everything, when the user is about to finalize the transaction, I would like to, if the user is a member/logged in, use `$this->Auth->user('id')` to get their authenticated ID and attach it to the order that is about to be finalized. For the life that is left in me, I can't get it to work. This is what I am doing:

I have the following class:

```
    public function review() {
    $shop = $this->Session->read('Shop');       
    if(empty($shop)) {
        $this->redirect('/shop/cart');
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->loadModel('Order');
        $this->Order->set($this->request->data);
        if($this->Order->validates()) {
            $order = $shop;
            $order['Order']['user_id'] = (int)$this->Auth->user('id');
            $order['Order']['status'] = 1;

            var_dump($order);

            if($shop['Order']['order_type'] == 'paypal') {
                $paypal = $this->Paypal->ConfirmPayment($order['Order']['total']);
                $ack = strtoupper($paypal['ACK']);
                if($ack == 'SUCCESS' || $ack == 'SUCCESSWITHWARNING') {
                    $order['Order']['status'] = 2;
                }
                $order['Order']['authorization'] = $paypal['ACK'];
            }
            $save = $this->Order->saveAll($order, array('validate' => 'first'));
            if($save) {
                $this->set(compact('shop'));
                App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
                $email = new CakeEmail();
                $email->from($this->requestAction('/settings/getSettingValue/ADMIN_EMAIL'))
                        ->cc($this->requestAction('/settings/getSettingValue/ADMIN_EMAIL'))
                        ->to($shop['Order']['email'])
                        ->subject('Shop Order')
                        ->emailFormat('text')
                        ->viewVars(array('shop' => $shop))
                        ->send();
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'success'));
            } else {
                $errors = $this->Order->invalidFields();
                $this->set(compact('errors'));
            }
        }           
    }
    if(($shop['Order']['order_type'] == 'paypal') && !empty($shop['Paypal']['Details'])) {
        $shop['Order']['first_name'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['FIRSTNAME'];
        $shop['Order']['last_name'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['LASTNAME'];
        $shop['Order']['email'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['EMAIL'];
        $shop['Order']['phone'] = '888-888-8888';
        $shop['Order']['billing_address'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['SHIPTOSTREET'];
        $shop['Order']['billing_address2'] = '';
        $shop['Order']['billing_city'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['SHIPTOCITY'];
        $shop['Order']['billing_zip'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['SHIPTOZIP'];
        $shop['Order']['billing_state'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['SHIPTOSTATE'];
        $shop['Order']['billing_country'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME'];
        $shop['Order']['shipping_address'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['SHIPTOSTREET'];
        $shop['Order']['shipping_address2'] = '';
        $shop['Order']['shipping_city'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['SHIPTOCITY'];
        $shop['Order']['shipping_zip'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['SHIPTOZIP'];
        $shop['Order']['shipping_state'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['SHIPTOSTATE'];
        $shop['Order']['shipping_country'] = $shop['Paypal']['Details']['SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME'];
        $shop['Order']['order_type'] = 'paypal';
        $this->Session->write('Shop.Order', $shop['Order']);
    }
    $this->set(compact('shop'));
}
```

At line 11, I add the logged in user ID to the `$order` array by doing the following:

```
$order['Order']['user_id'] = (int)$this->Auth->user('id');
```

At this point if I do a `var_dump($order)`, I will see whatever user id is for the currently logged in user, in this case `18`. So I know for a fact that I am assigning it correctly.

```
 ["user_id"]=> int(18)
```

Everything is fine up to here. However, when I check my DB the `user_id` field is NULL. `18` is not being saved as added to the array. I have done multiple things and I cant see what am I doing wrong. Please help!

My `orders` table structure look like this:

[image]

And one of the order entry look like this:

[image]

I run out of ideas and I dont know what to do.....

Comment: Is this function is called after returning from paypal i.e when user click on the success url or cancel url.

Comment: This is called after payment has been approved in Paypal, so after success. Everything works great: Order is added, etc. I just cant fill the user_id field with the correct user ID. That is all I really want to accomplish. I am scratching my head, as it just dont make sense why I cant....

Comment: is `var_dump($order)` showing user_id in `$order array`

Comment: Yes... as I posted above, it shows it as `["user_id"]=> int(18)`, with 18 being the ID of whatever user is logged in at the moment. It could also be `["user_id"]=> int(1)`

Comment: After some more digging, I decided to change the Db field to `user` instead of `user_id` and it worked. Why isnt it taking `user_id`. My user model `$hasMany = array('Order'=>array('foreignKey' => 'user'))`. It would be STANDARD to use `user_id`. I just cant figure out why it is not allowing it. So far the fix works!

Comment: @CaboONE how about answer your own question, for the community's benefit?

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, I decided to change the Db field to `user` instead of `user_id` and it worked. Why isnt it taking `user_id`. My user model `$hasMany = array('Order'=>array('foreignKey' => 'user'))`. It would be STANDARD to use `user_id`. I just cant figure out why it is not allowing it. So far the fix works!

Comment: The user model you posted just now is what you have now or what you had when you posted the question?